# How to display the result of a JSP page in the same submitted page?

Tags: jsp, struts

I'm using struts 1.3.8. In JSP i have some search facility. Once the user presses the search button the result will come in the form of records.
How can i display the resultant records in the same search page under the search button?? 
Please reply soon..
Thanks in Advance
Regards,
Laxman Chowdary

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Make the form submit itself, and generate the page with the same search form, pre-filled with what the user has submitted, and with the results of the search after the form. That's the typical "Web 1.0" way of doing, and Struts form fields are well suited to this task.
2. Use JavaScript to send an AJAX request to the server when the form is submitted, and make the server generate a partial page, containing only the search results. In the AJAX response handler, insert the search results into the DOM tree of the page. The server could also answer with raw search results (i.e. not HTML formatted), using JSON for example, and the JavaScript response handler would then iterate through the results and create the appropriate HTML elements in the DOM dynamically.

EDIT:

To elaborate on the first way of doing: have two actions (`showSearchForm` and `executeSearch`) that both use the same ActionForm (containing the search form fields).

The first action just fills the form with default search values, and dispatches to a JSP that displays the form and the results. Since there is no result to display, it will just show the search form.

The second action validates the form, executes the search, stores the search results into a request attribute or into the ActionForm directly, and then dispatches to the same JSP as the first action. This time, the JSP will find results to display, and will thus display them.

Comment: Hi Nizet, Can you elaborate the first way of doing the result displaying on the same page..

Comment: @JBNizet nice non ajax way +1

Comment: @JBNizet, why not we simply use single Action with two dispatcher methods. Both methods results in same JSP?

Comment: You can of course use a single DipatchAction subclass to implement both actions (is that what you mean?). But it's logical to have two actions since one needs validation and the other does not, and the URLs should be different.

Comment: Hi Nizet, I found one more nice solution finally. Struts providing tags like logic,html and bean.Using <logic:nonEmpty> with one property first time is null. when we send the request and the result will come with that property and the forward page is same JSP page. By this time <logic:nonEmpty> is true bcoz the property is not null. So the body of the tag will execute and displays the result what we expected.

Comment: Yes, that's what I intended with "Since there is no result to display, it will just show the search form". Don't use logic tags (and most of the bean tags). Use the JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax.

If I do it with jQuery

```
jQuery.ajax(
    url: getSomething, 
    datatype: "JSON",
    success:function(data){
     //parse and call add new records in the table
 });
```

Or

Again use Ajax, in struts say you place the retrieved record in session.

Then there is another jsp which has the logic or reading the session attribute and creating a html table, just return that page. Since data is already in the session your jsp will be populated. So your ajax call will look like:

```
jQuery.ajax(
        url: getSomething, 
        success:function(data){
         jQuery('#IdOfElementWhereTheHTMLTableNeedsToBeAdded').append(data);
     });
```

Comment: Hi Prabhat, I'm not aware of Jquery.. I know only AJAX.Can you tell me other possible solution ????????

Comment: Hi Laxman, you can follow the old style ajax and in your onreadystatechange  method you will receive data, once you have received data instead of saying jQuery.append you will say document.getElementById().appendChild(data), jQuery just makes it easy to get going, its still a javascript lib

Comment: Prabhat, My form has multiple form elements.How can i send all using AJAX? I worked with drop down kind of thing using AJAX.First Why AJAX here? is there any simple solution without AJAX? Bcoz if i use ajax, the form data can't be populated to the Form Bean. we have to do it explicitly. so can you tell me other possible solution???????

Comment: @JB Nizet has explained very nicely non ajax version, I dont think I have anything else to add to it :)